Big-Oh $\sin$ Proof
I want to prove that $\sin(x)=O(1)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$
I know there are different methods of solving. Are all these appropriate?
Method $1$:
I want to prove that $|\sin(x)| \leq K|1|$ whenever $x>M$ where there exist constants $K,M>0$ satisfying this.
I do $|\sin(x)| \leq 1 = 1 \cdot |1| $, so there exist constants $K=1$ and $M$ can be any positive number satisfying this.
Method $2$:
Observe that $\lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} |\frac{\sin{x}}{1}| = \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} |\sin{x}| \leq 1$
As this limit is finite, then this means $\sin{x}$ is bounded by a multiple of the function $1$, so $\sin(x)=O(1)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

$\lim_{x\to \infty}|\sin x|$ does not exist, so what's the meaning of $\lim_{x\to \infty}|\sin x|\le 1$?

I believe you followed this: $0 \leq |\sin x| \leq 1$ and thus $\lim_{x\to\infty}{0} \leq \lim_{x\to\infty}{|\sin x|} \leq \lim_{x\to\infty}{1}$, $0 \leq \lim_{x\to\infty}{|\sin x|} \leq 1$? These statements are null as $|\sin x|$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$ to infinity.

@SineoftheTime I meant that the limit can't be greater than $1$ but you are right it doesn't exist, so method $2$ shouldn't be used. Was my method $1$ correct?

As other contributors have said, method 2 does not work because the limit does not exist.  However, all we need is for the limit superior to exist.  We have:
$$\limsup_{x\to\infty} \bigg|\frac{\sin x}{1}\bigg| = \lim_{M\to\infty}\sup_{x\geq M} |\sin x| = \lim_{M\to\infty} 1 = 1 <\infty,$$
so $\sin x = O(1)$.  I'd say this is the corrected version of your method 2.
However, to show that $\sup_{x\geq M}|\sin x| = 1$, we end up using $|\sin x| \leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so method 1 is still preferable.

I checked my notes and the supremum was in the definition which I missed out. Thank you.

Accordingly to definition
$$O(g(x)),x \to x_0=  \left\lbrace f\colon\exists C > 0, \exists \delta>0 , \forall x \in U_{\delta}(x_0), |f(x)| \leqslant C \cdot |g(x)| \right\rbrace $$
where $U_{\delta}(x_0)$ is $\delta$ neighbourhood of $x_0$. As in your case $x_0=\infty$, then it is set $|x|>\delta$, so you do not need limit at all and of course $\sin(x)=O(1), x\to \infty$ holds, because $|\sin(x)| \leqslant 1$ holds everywhere.

So I should only use method $1$ for this question? Was my working in method $1$ okay?

Yes, 1-st is enough, especially since, as is pointed in comments, limit doesn't exists.

Thanks. Was it okay that I said it is true for all $M>0$? If I just said before doing the proof let $M=2$ or any other positive number, that would also work right?

Yes. As  $|\sin(x)| \leqslant 1$ holds everywhere, than you can use any $M>0$.
